# Create Vector B Using Position and Direction of Vector A

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I am currently trying to understand how to go about creating a vector at a specific position relative to the position and direction of another vector. For example, I have this illustration which might help explain what I am trying to accomplish:

[image]

Point `A` contains properties: `glm::vec3 position` and `glm::vec3 direction`. Now let's say I want point `B` to be 2 units in front of `A`. Is there a way to solve this mathematically using glm to determine the position of `B`?

Comment: What is "in front of" in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A point on a ray can be get by:

```
B = A + D * t
```

where `A` is the origin of the ray, `D` is a the direction vector with length 1 ([`Unit vector`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector)) and `t` is the distance form `A` to `B`.

With the [GLM](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/index.html) this can be expressed like this:

```cpp
struct Ray
{
    glm::vec3 position;
    glm::vec3 direction;
};

Ray A;
```

```cpp
float t = 2.0f;
glm::vec3 B = A.position + glm::normalize(A.direction) * t;
```

[`normalize()`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00697.html#ga3b8d3dcae77870781392ed2902cce597) calculates a vector in the same direction as the given vector, but with length of 1.

If the direction vector is stored as a unit vector (with length 1), then the expensive `normalize()` operation can be avoided, when a point on the ray is calculated.
I recommend to define a `class Ray` which can calculate a point on the ray:

```cpp
class Ray
{
public:

   Ray(const glm::vec3 &O, const glm::vec3 &D)
     : _O(O)
     , _D(glm::normalize(D))
   {}

   glm::vec3 P(float t) const {
       return _O + _D * t;
   }

private:
    glm::vec3 _O;
    glm::vec3 _D;
};
```

```cpp
Ray A(glm::vec3(....), glm::vec3(....));
```

```cpp
glm::vec3 B = A.P( 2.0f );
```

Answer (score 0):

Point B would have position which is equal to Point A's position + Point A's direction times 2, since (I'm assuming here) the direction is a unit vector of length 1.

```
glm::vec3 positionB = a.pos + a.dir * 2.f;
```

Comment: No! You forgot to normalize `a.dir`.  If you don't normalize it, then it will be 2 dir lengths in front of A, not two units in front of A.

Comment: @mackycheese21 Wouldn't you assume a field called `direction` is already normalized?

Comment: Not necesarilly, no.  Direction could mean anything from velocity to actual direction.  And normalization is such a simple operation, and it gives you such an important gaurantee, that it's worth it to have.

Comment: I realize that it has a square root which is slow, but consider this: If the speed of square roots is slowing your computer down, either you are misusing GLM and should be using GPU / GLSL / OpenCL, or you are on a potato and no-one can help you.

Comment: @mackycheese21 I find your last statement a bit ridiculous. Any attempt to optimize CPU code is futile, just use GPUs instead?

Comment: no.  If your code is so slow that removing square roots seems the best route to efficiency, then you have other issues.  What I meant was that if a single square root was slowing you down, then you are probably doing way too many GLM operations and you should consider moving them to the GPU.  The GPU is very good at repeated things.  GLM is best for once-per-frame calculations.

Comment: @mackycheese21 It's a futile argument. If performance is an issue, you should never be in a position where you don't know whether or not the data you're operating on is normalized. If it is, you absolutely don't need to re-normalize, otherwise you definitely do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193789/discussion-between-mackycheese21-and-rotem).